# IF(OR(AND function to select data between two values for more times

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula

I have this formula to select data between two timeperiodes for FOUR time periodes. 
But this formula is really long.
by using IF(OR(AND(starttimefirst period);(endtime first period))AND (starttime second period)(endtime secondperiod) and so on.

I'm just wondering if there is a method where this formula can be a lot shorter because I lost count with brackets a lot of times. Also this formule will be in a lot of cells so the computer will need more time to calculate!?

this is the formula I have now:

```
=VALUE(IF(OR(AND(Sheet1!$E23>=($A$1+TIME($C$4;$D$4;$E$4));Sheet1!$E23<($A$1+TIME($C$5;$D$5;$E$5)));(AND(Sheet1!$E23>=($A$1+TIME($C$6;$D$6;$E$6));Sheet1!$E23<($A$1+TIME($C$7;$D$7;$E$7))));(AND(Sheet1!$E23>=($A$1+TIME($C$8;$D$8;$E$8));(Sheet1!$E23<($A$1+TIME($C$9;$D$9;$E$9)))));(AND(Sheet1!$E23>=($A$1+TIME($C$10;$D$10;$E$10));Sheet1!$E23<$A$1+(TIME($C$11;$D$11;$E$11)))));Sheet1!O23;"0"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the formula

```
=TIME($C4,$D4,$E4)
```

into column F to generate timestamps, then use the formula

```
=VALUE(IF(OR(
AND(Sheet1!$E23>=$A$1+$F$4,Sheet1!$E23<$A$1+$F$5),
AND(Sheet1!$E23>=$A$1+$F$6,Sheet1!$E23<$A$1+$F$7),
AND(Sheet1!$E23>=$A$1+$F$8,Sheet1!$E23<$A$1+$F$9),
AND(Sheet1!$E23>=$A$1+$F$10,Sheet1!$E23<$A$1+$F$11)),Sheet1!$O$23,"0"))
```

Linebreaks aren't essential, but makes it easier to maintain. Also, relax with the brackets. Excel does arithmetic before it checks things like inequalities.